# Base64 Encoded Data - DB or Filesystem

Tags: database, filesystems, base64

I have a new program that will be generating a lot of Base64 encoded audio and image data. This data will be served via HTTP in the form of XML and the Base64 data will be inline. These files will most likely break 20MB and higher. Would it be more efficient to serve these files directly from the filesystem or would it be feasible to store the data in a MySQL database? Caching will be set up but overall unnecessary because it is likely that this data will be purged shortly after it is created and served.

i know that storing binary data in the DB is frowned upon in most circumstances but since this will all be character data I want to see what the consensus is. As of now, I am leaning toward storing them in the filesystem for efficiency reasons but if it is feasible to store them in a database it would be much easier to manage the data.

Comment: Save the original file on filesystem and encode with base64 on-the-fly.

Comment: The reason that storing binary data in the DB is frowned upon is not that the data is binary, but rather that it is *immutable* and does not participate in the information logic that the database models. The same is true for the base64-representation of the data, so it too should best go into separate storage and the DB should only maintain an index.

Comment: I was leaning toward that logic Kerrek. on-the-fly encoding may be feasible but likely I will need to generate the file beforehand and store it somewhere. It is sounding like storing this data, no matter what form it is in, will be better suited for the filesystem. That is what I was leaning toward in the first place so I suppose I can live with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to weigh several factors:

- **Speed of access** If you dump all your files in the filesystem, then some filesystems break or slow way down when you have too many files. I have seen many different directory segmentation schemes to address this issue.
- **Compression** MySQL can easily compress your stored data. With a filesystem it may be harder to compress data. Using any kind of compression  compression also raises a concern with the CPU speed on your server.
- **Backup/Restore** A DB is made for easy backup/restore, how easy or hard it is for a filesystem varies greatly. If you have data in the filesystem to back/restore then that makes your backup/restore more complicated, and complicated is not good in a crisis.
- **Data loss tolerance** With a DB you manipulate a record and all data is there in the same place. If you save your data to a file, you need to manipulate the associated file with extra code, and this this introduces another place to have bugs and possible data loss. More specifically, if you store part of the record in the filesystem and the rest in the DB, you need to go to great lengths to maintain transactional integrity.  Nobody cares about this until you lose data, so pay attention to this aspect even though it may not seem important.
- **Replication** It is easier to deal with replication concerns if you only have to do it at one level. Storing your data only in the DB and then replicating only the DB is far easier than doing that for the DB and also for the file system.
- **Cumbersomeness** It is just more cumbersome to deal with larger DB backups than it is with smaller DB backups.

Those are the top issues that come to mind. I tried not to advocate for either solution, it really depends heavily on which file system you are talking about as well, and since that is not specified, you need to make that decision yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. The files will be stored in ext4 filesystem. From the other comments here, I'm probably going to go with FS storage.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can store any bytes you like in a database (using appropriate "blob" types). Databases do not need to contain character-only data.

Second, it would be a waste of space (25% of your space, specifically) to store the base64-encoded data on disk or in a database. Store the *actual* bytes, and then base64-encode the bytes on the way out of the HTTP server.

If your purging policy is as short as you indicate, you may be better off *not* storing the data anywhere at all, and generating it on demand every time it is needed. That way, it's impossible to have any problems with your caching layer, because there isn't one.

Comment: I am not asking this, I need the data to be Base64 encoded for purposes beyond storage.

Comment: It's *still* likely to be cheaper (in time, space, and money) to base64-encode your data whenever you need it, rather than actually storing it that way.

Comment: The data also does need to be stored, even though it is temporary, because it will be edited multiple times before being served in its final form.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot more requirements than what you've described in your question.

Comment: No... I said I am generating XML files containing base64 encoded data. I want to know if it is better to store this XML file on the filesystem or to store it in a database.